# TS2740 error when trying to assign an array of strings

Tags: typescript, azure-ad-msal

I have the following code to grab groups off of Azure Msal object.

```js
const azureGroupId = process.env.REACT_APP_AZURE_TIMELOGS_GROUP_ID;
const account = accounts[0];
const accountGroups: string[] = account.idTokenClaims?.groups || [];
const isAuthorizedUser = accountGroups.some(group => {
  return group === azureGroupId;
});
```

On the line `const accountGrouips: string[] = account.idTokenClaims?.groups || [];` I get a TS2740 error "Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'string[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 29 more."

I need to be able to break out the groups and compare to the group that should exist in the env variable. Works fine JS but not TS.

Comment: Looks from error type that `account.idTokenClaims?.groups` is not an Array - maybe it is an object?